# On derivative of complex number

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, number-theory

My doubt is what is a derivative. I know that derivative is slope of tangent of function we have chosen. But now I am new to complex analysis and just learnt about differentials and my query is that "is complex derivatives taken for paths of complex numbers or simply complex numbers" my teachers say that it's for complex numbers but I don't find where is tangent.  I am new to complex analysis and don't know about contour integration and others so I request the readers to answer in a simpler.way. thank you

Comment: If you are already in the chapter of Contour Integration, that means you got to be struggling for some time now, right? But derivatives are not only used for the tangent problem. You should have known that from real calculus before you took on this course.How did you go by the Chapter that deals with Cauchy Riemann equations?

Comment: I find this introduction quite nice http://www1.spms.ntu.edu.sg/~ydchong/teaching/06_complex_derivatives.pdf

Comment: When you generalize a concept, *some old meanings no longer make sense*. There are *many* interpretations of the classical real derivative, not just the tangent slope. Give up on the tangent slope viewpoint and use others, such as being a coefficients in a "best linear approximation".  Even earlier in your mathematical education you had to do this: do you think $a^{1/2}$ means multiplying $a$ by itself "1/2 time"? That makes no sense, so you already had to *give up* on the idea that exponents are repeated multiplication in order to extend exponents to numbers that are not positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to abstract from the real case.
When we say that $f(x)=3x^2$ has derivative $f'(2)=12$ at $x=2$, this means that near $x=2$, our $f$ is nicely approximated by the linear function $g(x)=f(2)+12\cdot(x-2)$. And with "nicely approximated", we mean that $|g(x)-f(x)|$ is small compared to $|x-2|$ for $x\approx  2$. This way, we got rid of all geometric concepts and can transfer to the complex case:
We say $f'(z_0)=c$ if $f'(z)= f(z_0)+c\cdot (z-z_0)+o(z-z_0)$ where $o$ is a function that is (in a well formalizable sense) small near $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative $g^\prime(x)$ of a real function $g(x)$ is $$ g^\prime(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}.$$

The derivative $f^\prime(z)$ of a function of a complex variable $f(z)$ is $$ f^\prime(z) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z+h)-g(z)}{h}.$$

These may look similar (actually, the definitions are exactly the same, other than the "names" of the variables and functions).  The difference, though, is that in the complex case, whatever direction $h$ approaches zero, the limit must be the same for the derivative to exist.  This has far reaching implications!  Since it's much more difficult for a function to have a derivative, when a function is differentiable, there are consequences.

For a complex function $f$ that has a derivative:

0. The partial derivatives of the real and imaginary parts of $f$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.
1. If $f^\prime(z)$ exists, so does $f^{\prime\prime}(z)$.  This implies that $f$ is infinitely differentiable (not true for real functions).
2. If $f^\prime(z)$ exists in a region, $f$ is analytic, and has a power series representation.
3. You will see that if $f^\prime(z)$ exists in a region, then for a simple closed curve $C$ in the region, $\oint_C f(z) \, dz = 0$.